# Full text search is not working as expectation in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, full-text-search

I have created rds medium instance for query and also full-text index that table. It is supposed to give results quickly within 0.06 to 0.08 sec but it is taking 0.19 sec approximately which is slower than the expected time
There are only 28000 records in database at the moment

Here is how I am using query

```
 SELECT * FROM `consignments` WHERE MATCH(barcode) AGAINST('"CXV910640-08"' IN Boolean MODE)
```

Where I need to improve it?

Comment: Can you give more information about the content of that column? Especially if it only contains a single barcode (e.g. just the value `CXV910640-08` without anything before it), a fulltext search might be the wrong tool here. Otherwise, can you test execution time and number of results for "CXV910640" (without the "-08").

Comment: yes it is only  single value i don't want to use wild card here and without `08` it can give upto 200 results

Comment: If it is the only value, create a normal index and do `where barcode = 'CXV910640-08'`. Execution time will be around 0.001s (so below your requirement of 0.06s). A fulltext index is designed as a tool to find words in sentences.